# Racing CDI installation on Kymco Sento 50cc scooter

Tags: cdi

I recently purchased a performance kit from J and J, with carb, air filter coil and racing CDI. When I put the new CDI in, it blew the fuses. Replaced the fuses, tried again, same result. Had to put the old CDI back on. I haven't put any of the other components on as a result. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the current rating of the new ignition? What size are the fuses that blew?

Comment: ... and are you sure you have the new CDI wired correctly?

Answer (score 1):

An AC version of the CDI will blow the main fuse if installed in a Kymco DC scooter.  Sometimes it's difficult to tell one from the other, they look similar.  Make sure you're installing a DC CDI, not an AC.